# Logstash: Output to Elasticsearch gives errors with ruby but works with stdout

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash

The error is related to the ruby code, how do I fix this ?

Config:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    ssl => false
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "apache" {
ruby {
code => " if event['message']
event['message'] = event['message'].gsub('\x','Xx')
event['message'] = event['message'].gsub('\x','XXx')
end
"
}

json {
      source => "message"
    }
}
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    sniffing => true
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }
}
```

Logstash log:

> {:timestamp=>"2016-07-01T13:23:30.475000+0100", :message=>"Connection
>   refused", :class=>"Manticore::SocketException",
>   :backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.6.0-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:37:in
>   initialize'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281:incall'",
>   "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.6.0-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:79:in
>   call'",
>   "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.6.0-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:256:incall_once'",
>   "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.6.0-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:153:in
>   code'",
>   "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.18/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/manticore.rb:84:inperform_request'",
>   "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281:in call'",
>   "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.18/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:257:inperform_request'",
>   "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.18/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/manticore.rb:67:in
>   perform_request'",
>   "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.18/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/sniffer.rb:32:inhosts'", "org/jruby/ext/timeout/Timeout.java:147:in timeout'",
>   "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.18/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/sniffer.rb:31:inhosts'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.18/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:79:in
>   reload_connections!'",
>   "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.7.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:72:insniff!'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.7.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:60:in
>   start_sniffing!'",
>   "org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:149:insynchronize'",
>   "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.7.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:60:in
>   start_sniffing!'", "org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1479:inloop'",
>   "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.7.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:59:in
>   `start_sniffing!'"], :level=>:error}
>   {:timestamp=>"2016-07-01T13:23:52.470000+0100",
>   :message=>"CircuitBreaker::rescuing exceptions", :name=>"Beats input",
>   :exception=>LogStash::Inputs::Beats::InsertingToQueueTakeTooLong,
>   :level=>:warn} {:timestamp=>"2016-07-01T13:23:52.470000+0100",
>   :message=>"Beats input: The circuit breaker has detected a slowdown or
>   stall in the pipeline, the input is closing the current connection and
>   rejecting new connection until the pipeline recover.",
>   :exception=>LogStash::Inputs::BeatsSupport::CircuitBreaker::HalfOpenBreaker,
>   :level=>:warn} {:timestamp=>"2016-07-01T13:23:52.471000+0100",
>   :message=>"CircuitBreaker::rescuing exceptions", :name=>"Beats input",
>   :exception=>LogStash::Inputs::Beats::InsertingToQueueTakeTooLong,
>   :level=>:warn} {:timestamp=>"2016-07-01T13:23:52.471000+0100",
>   :message=>"Beats input: The circuit breaker has detected a slowdown or
>   stall in the pipeline, the input is closing the current connection and
>   rejecting new connection until the pipeline recover.",
>   :exception=>LogStash::Inputs::BeatsSupport::CircuitBreaker::HalfOpenBreaker,
>   :level=>:warn} {:timestamp=>"2016-07-01T13:23:53.471000+0100",
>   :message=>"Beats input: the pipeline is blocked, temporary refusing
>   new connection.", :reconnect_backoff_sleep=>0.5, :level=>:warn}
>   {:timestamp=>"2016-07-01T13:23:53.472000+0100",
>   :message=>"CircuitBreaker::Open", :name=>"Beats input", :level=>:warn}
>   {:timestamp=>"2016-07-01T13:23:53.473000+0100", :message=>"Beats
>   input: The circuit breaker has detected a slowdown or stall in the
>   pipeline, the input is closing the current connection and rejecting
>   new connection until the pipeline recover.",
>   :exception=>LogStash::Inputs::BeatsSupport::CircuitBreaker::OpenBreaker,
>   :level=>:warn} {:timestamp=>"2016-07-01T13:23:53.972000+0100",
>   :message=>"Beats input: the pipeline is blocked, temporary refusing
>   new connection.", :reconnect_backoff_sleep=>0.5, :level=>:warn}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by deleting the indexes from elasticsearch.

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/filebeat-*'
```

Note that the ruby does not work. I had to change my log format to combined log to handle the exception.

Comment: If you want to do string replacement in logstash, you can use the mutate filter with gsub : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub. And you can have conditionals in your configuration https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not from the ruby code, but from your connection to Elasticsearch.

In your stacktrace:

> "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/**logstash-output-elasticsearch**-2.7.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:59:in

Either your Elasticsearch instance is not started or can not be reached by logstash.

Comment: You are correct, can we start a discussion on how I can restore this connection ? It used to work before I inserted the ruby code, I had to kill -9 logstash and elasticsearch as I couldnt stop the processes safely. I started it up then it has been establishing connections by checking `lsof -i :9200`. But I get this error in the logstash: `Beats input: the pipeline is blocked, temporary refusing new connection.`

Comment: I think this error `Beats input: the pipeline is blocked, temporary refusing new connection.` is caused by the connection problem to elasticsearch. To check if Elasticsearch is running and available, I use `curl localhost:9200`. Could you check this first?

Comment: I used that command, and get back the name and settings of elasticsearch.

Comment: My elasticsearch log out is:
`[2016-07-04 11:58:38,792][WARN ][cluster.routing.allocation.decider] [Ultra-Marine] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [YMlUds73Q9WSvS2bk7WKAA][Ultra-Marine][/var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 23.7gb[8.7%], shards will be relocated away from this node`

Comment: According to this logs, Elasticsearch is running out of disk space. if it is the case across all your nodes, Elasticsearch might stop accepting connections because of it. You could try to make some room and try again

Comment: Beyond that, I don't have any other idea.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I resolved the issue by deleting my indexes in elasticsearch